# Save figures to have the same size independet of x ticks, ylabels

Tags: python, matplotlib, save, png, figure

I am trying to create some figures for publication. When I insert them into latex they don't line up well. Essentially because the x ticks and labels are different they end up looking like this:

[image]

The code  am using to save those figures is the following:

```
size_f = 20
#### Set labels ####
ax.set_ylabel(r'$W_{kin} \ [eV]$', fontsize=size_f)
ax.set_xlabel(r'$Time \  [sec]$', fontsize=size_f)


#### Set fig dimensions ####
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [10,8]

#### Set tick size ####
ax.tick_params(axis='x',labelsize=size_f)
ax.tick_params(axis='y',labelsize=size_f)


#### Save figure ####
fig.savefig(r'C:\Users\nikos.000\vlahos\png\Dw_UCS.png', format='png',dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')
```

How could I make the boxes have the same size so the figures line up better, independently of the axis ticks and labels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I strongly recommend you to use [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html). You can adjust features of each subplot without disordering general appearance. I add code for you to use your project.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = range(10)
y = range(10)

size_f = 12

labels = ("(a)", "(b)", "(c)", "(d)")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, 2, figsize=(10, 8))
ax[0, 0].plot(x, y, 'r')
ax[0, 0].text(-0.1, 1., labels[0], transform=ax[0, 0].transAxes, fontsize=15, fontweight='normal', va='top', ha='right')
ax[0, 1].plot(x, y, 'b') 
ax[0, 1].text(-0.1, 1., labels[1], transform=ax[0, 1].transAxes, fontsize=15, fontweight='normal', va='top', ha='right')
ax[1, 0].plot(x, y, 'g') 
ax[1, 0].text(-0.1, 1., labels[2], transform=ax[1, 0].transAxes, fontsize=15, fontweight='normal', va='top', ha='right')
ax[1, 1].plot(x, y, 'k') 
ax[1, 1].text(-0.1, 1., labels[3], transform=ax[1, 1].transAxes, fontsize=15, fontweight='normal', va='top', ha='right')

for row in range(2):
    for col in range(2):
        ax[row, col].set_ylabel(r'$W_{kin} \ [eV]$', fontsize=size_f)
        ax[row, col].set_xlabel(r'$Time \  [sec]$', fontsize=size_f)

fig.subplots_adjust(wspace=0.3)
fig.subplots_adjust(hspace=0.3) 
fig.savefig(r'C:\Users\nikos.000\vlahos\png\Dw_UCS.png', format='png',dpi=300,bbox_inches='tight')
```

The figure:
[image]

Since you will have common and independent features for each subplot, I didn't put everything into `for-blocks`.

Comment: Thanks! orks great! Do you knwo how I could change the size of the labels?

Comment: Do you ask for fontSize of labels?  In `ax[row, col].set_ylabel(r'$W_{kin} \ [eV]$', fontsize=size_f)`, just change `size_f`. But, I guess, you want to learn a different thing. Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: Or are you talking about labels for (a), (b) etc? Then in `ax[0, 0].text(-0.1, 1., labels[0], transform=ax[0, 0].transAxes, fontsize=15, fontweight='normal', va='top', ha='right')` increase `fontsize` parameter from 15 to 18 or more. Be sure that you apply all subplots. (`ax[0, 0], ax[0, 1], ax[1, 0], ax[1, 1]`)

Answer (score 0):

Use [matplotlib.pyplot.subplots](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.3/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplots.html) to get multiple plots in the same image neatly.